# Modify C# code to handle multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, foreach, async-await

I wrote this code which gets all this data from some some devices and displays it in a Windows Forms app. Instead of looking at each device sequentially with that foreach loop I'd really like to do them all at once. Where should I begin to accomplish this?

I believe my main hang ups are that Lists are not thread safe and being able to add to the allPackages list from all the different devices so I can sort it at the end. It also has been an issue that I need the method to be async for the DevicePortal methods.

I don't have very much experience, so any and all suggestions are welcome.

```
private async void LoadPrograms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetPanelEnabledProperty(false);
        try
        {
            List<packageItem> allPackages = new List<packageItem>();

            foreach (Uri uri in uriList)
            {
                try
                {
                    DevicePortal portal = GetPortal(uri);

                    //finds all app packages on the devices
                    DevicePortal.AppPackages apps = await portal.GetInstalledAppPackagesAsync();

                    foreach (DevicePortal.PackageInfo package in apps.Packages)
                    {
                        allPackages.Add(new packageItem
                        {
                            name = package.Name,
                            packageName = package.FullName
                        });
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            //Find all instances of packageNames that have a count > 1
            IEnumerable<packageItem> duplicates = allPackages
                    .GroupBy(item => item.packageName)
                    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                    .Select(g => g.First());

            //populate the second listBox
            //If there's only one device we ignore the logic we just did and just use all the packages in that device
            listBox2.DataSource = uriList.Count == 1 ? allPackages : duplicates.ToList();
            listBox2.DisplayMember = "name";
            listBox2.ValueMember = "packageName";
        }
        finally
        {
            this.SetPanelEnabledProperty(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: For me, get the book C# X(mine is 4.0) in a nutshell book.  That being said, I'll look into the parallel foreach: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx  I am far from an expert at it, but it has worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,  your for each loop will call an Asynchronous method that will run a task on each available thread and give you want you need.

you might want to put an await command in there too to ensure all tasks are complete before moving on.

```
private async void LoadPrograms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.SetPanelEnabledProperty(false);
  try
  {
    List<packageItem> allPackages = new List<packageItem>();

    foreach (Uri uri in uriList)
    {
        CallAsyncMethod(uri)
    }
    //Find all instances of packageNames that have a count > 1
    IEnumerable<packageItem> duplicates = allPackages
            .GroupBy(item => item.packageName)
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .Select(g => g.First());

    //populate the second listBox
    //If there's only one device we ignore the logic we just did and just use all the packages in that device
    listBox2.DataSource = uriList.Count == 1 ? allPackages : duplicates.ToList();
    listBox2.DisplayMember = "name";
    listBox2.ValueMember = "packageName";
}
finally
{
    this.SetPanelEnabledProperty(true);
}
}

private static Task CallAsyncMethod(Uri uri)
{
return Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        DevicePortal portal = GetPortal(uri);

        //finds all app packages on the devices
        DevicePortal.AppPackages apps = await portal.GetInstalledAppPackagesAsync();

        foreach (DevicePortal.PackageInfo package in apps.Packages)
        {
            allPackages.Add(new packageItem
            {
                name = package.Name,
                packageName = package.FullName
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
});
}
```